Please explain why datasheet says to connect the feedback resistors in a particular way
The datasheet for the AD667 DAC shows how to connect the output to internal feedback resistors in different ways, in order to get different output voltage ranges.

For output range of 0 to +5 V, it says to connect the output to pin 2, a 5k feedback resistor.
For output range of 0 to +10 V, it says to connect the output to both pins 1 and 2.

Pin 1 is also a 5k feedback resistor, which is in series with the pin 2 feedback resistor. So it seems that the feedback current would all go through pin 2, because the pin 1 feedback resistor is in parallel with a short.
It would make more sense to me if it said to connect pin 9 to ONLY pin 1 to get an output range of 0 to +10 V, that way the feedback resistance is 10k, twice as much as 5k, twice as much gain, so 10 V range instead of 5 V range.
Can anyone explain why they connect pin 9 to both pins 1 and 2?



Connecting just pin 1 to pin 9 gives you a 20V range, not 10V. You should include more of that table instead of cropping off the fourth column.

The difference is in the input codes that you failed to highlight. Offset binary is bipolar so it needs less gain to swing from the null point. Straight binary needs twice the gain (for a given bit) to operate in this unipolar mode of operation.
Electrically, what you are saying is correct. The reason they want you to "short" upper 5k is simply to keep the input from floating.

but the input is connectoed to 5k, not floating

@JasenСлаваУкраїні It's floating if you don't connect pin 1 to pin 2. Sure, internally Pin 1 is connected to a resistor. But where are you going to connect that pin with respect to "outside the chip"? Remember, that pin 1 resistor goes into the high impedance input of the opamp so it is very sensitive - normally, you can tie unused inputs to either, ground, V+, V-, or VCC/2 depending on the IC. But here it's part of the amp FB so it has to "ride" with pin 2 and pin 9 to stay equipotential during operation.

@JasenСлаваУкраїні Also, you don't want pin 1 to be an antenna while left open. Interference will couple into the FB path. Another reason is if there is any stray leakage currents on the board. This will manifest as an offset in output and compromise performance in your precious "true 12-bit DAC".

I understood your explanation for why we don't want to leave an input pin floating, but can you explain in more detail why the unipolar output range doubles when connecting pin 9 to both pin 1 and pin 2?

@charles see my comment on the question, you're missing the bigger picture

@charles That really should be opened in another question (site rules not to add new questions in comments). And I'm not going to be able to answer thoroughly in a comment. The quick answer is the GAIN is affected by these resistors and the DC (null) OFFSET is affected by the digital inputs. Post a new question if that's not clear.

it's not high impedance, it has an impedance of 5K into a connection to the output pin

@JasenСлаваУкраїні Pin 1, 2 & 3 are all pins back to the opamp input via 10k, 5k, & 0 ohms, respectively. Sure, you can argue there's also a 9.95k resistor on that node as well bringing the impendence down. And I've already mentioned shorting pin 1 and 2 is electrically equivalent. The exact impedance doesn't matter. In theory, you wouldn't even have the top 5k in the circuit if you weren't using that range. The point is you don't want to leave stray "resistors" floating hooked up to you FB node. It's bad practice. Since the IC is already fabbed with it there, the best you can do is short it.

@MOSFET I posted a new question:
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/716269/please-explain-how-these-two-different-dac-configurations-produce-different-outp
