Please explain how these two different DAC configurations produce different output voltage ranges
This question is regarding the AD667 DAC. In a previous question I learned that the pin 1 5k resistor does not affect the output voltage range for unipolar mode (assuming I understood the responses correctly). Could someone explain (in as much detail as you want) how the two different unipolar configurations produce the voltage ranges that they do?



What if you forget it's a DAC and simply look at the op-amp?

You misunderstood then. The 5k to pin 1 most certainly does affect the output voltage range.

@Justme that's exactly what I'm trying to do, I'm focusing on the op-amp and trying to understand that part of it

Let's first reduce the complexity to something that is easy to analyze: The DAC core is just a fancy current sink that is governed by some digital logic that controls an analog block. For the analysis, it's just a variable current sink that maxes out at 2mA when all 12-bits are "1" (this is the unipolar case, BTW). And this current will scale linearly down to 0mA as the bits fall to 0. So lets just consider the full scale (2mA) as our operating point for the analysis.
Pin 4 and the 9.95k resistor circuit is for trimming offsets due to manufacturing tolerancing. We will assume perfect parts for the analysis. So let's remove that distraction.
The 20pF capacitor between pins 2 and 3 is also another distraction. It doesn't affect the DC analysis and is there for compensating the opamp. We'll remove that capacitor.
This leaves you with the simplified model that represents the salient point of your question:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Next, let's make the wiring configurations spec'd out in the datasheet:

simulate this circuit

You have 5V SCALE and 10V SCALE the wrong way round. Larger feedback resistor means higher gain.

@Finbarr You're right. Corrected. Thanks

For the 0 V to + 10 V range you're right, the resistor to pin 1 isn't used as it's shorted out by the connection between pins 1 and 2. The feedback resistor for the opamp is therefore 5 kΩ.
For the 0 V to + 5 V range, pin 2 is connected to pin 9 and pin 1 is connected to pin 3, which puts the two 5 kΩ resistors in parallel to make 2.5 kΩ. This halves the gain of the opamp and hence halves the output voltage range.
Although it's only available in bipolar mode, the third configuration puts the two 5 kΩ resistors in series to make 10 kΩ and doubles the output range compared to the first mode.

thank you, I don't know why I couldn't see that before, even after redrawing it myself, but now I see how the two 5k resistors are in parallel for the +5V range. Thank you.
